# Group Email using MS Access

Tags: email, vba, ms-access

I'm using an MS access query in which I want to pull all the emails from the query and then populate an outlook email with all the emails, the code will run but, it does not pull in the email addresses and i cannot seem to figure out why.. here is what i have so far. My thoughts are than the query used in populating the table is not being called when trying to pull the emails

```
Private Sub Command30_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Command30_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    stDocName = "Department E-Mail"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit

    Dim r As Recordset
    Dim Email As String
    Set r = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT[tbl dmgrphcs].Email FROM [tbl  dmgrphcs]WHERE(([tbl     dmgrphcs].Email) Is Not Null);")

    Do While Not r.EOF
        Email = Email & r(0) & ";"
        r.MoveNext
    Loop
    r.Close

    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, Null, Null, "", "", Email, "", "", True, Null

Exit_Command30_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command30_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Command30_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Store your `SELECT` statement in a string variable, and `Debug.Print` the string.  Then if `OpenRecordset` throws an error or simply doesn't return the correct results, you can copy the actual `SELECT` statement from the Immediate window and test it as a new Access query.

Comment: Yes, Hans, or if the query does not change (as it seems to be the case here) store it as query. `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qselNonEmptyEMails")` makes the code look nicer.

Comment: hmm nothing seems to print when i run the print statment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of the table name is not consistent

```
[tbl dmgrphcs]
[tbl  dmgrphcs]
[tbl     dmgrphcs]
```

The number of spaces matters. If the query accesses only one table you don't need to prefix the columns with the table name

```
Set r = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Email FROM [tbl dmgrphcs] " & _
                                "WHERE Email Is Not Null")
```

---

Hint: Give your buttons meaningful names before adding event handlers. `Command30` does not speak. `btnPullEMails` or `cmdPullEMail` does. The event handler will then have a better name too:

```
Private Sub btnPullEMails_Click()
```

Comment: it still wont populate the email line, the query that is done docmd line is has more fields than just email, should that matter ?

Comment: You got the the send message command wrong. Your are adding the mail address to `Bcc` instead of `To`. `DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject,,,"EMail","CC","Bcc","Subject","Message"`

Comment: thanks that worked except, it shows the mailto part of the address and its querying the entire database, but its a start!